# Using Elasticsearch's multi-search API

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to figure out how to access the data that ES return using the multi-search API...

I'm using the API to perform a multi-match query and a mlt query. Using the multi-search API, ES returns a 'responses' array that gives results in the order of the search requests.

Normally, I would just access the data like this
es_return.hits.total (for total hits)

However, instead of just receiving data like this:

```
    {
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 11,
      "max_score": 4.2222037,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "query-index1",
            "_type": "autocomplete",
            "_id": "AVg00s--yzMyH55ObTRt",
            "_score": 4.2222037,
            "_source": {
               "suggestions": "term"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "query-index1",
            "_type": "autocomplete",
            "_id": "AVg00s--yzMyH55ObTRu",
            "_score": 2.6388774,
            "_source": {
               "suggestions": "term 1"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "query-index1",
            "_type": "autocomplete",
            "_id": "AVg00s--yzMyH55ObTRv",
            "_score": 2.6388774,
            "_source": {
               "suggestions": "term 2"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I now receive data like this:

```
    {
   "responses": [
      {
         "took": 66,
         "timed_out": false,
         "_shards": {
            "total": 1,
            "successful": 1,
            "failed": 0
         },
         "hits": {
            "total": 328,
            "max_score": 2.4221432,
            "hits": [
               {
                  "_index": "dev-4index",
                  "_type": "doc",
                  "_id": "http://www.example.com/something/",
                  "_score": 2.4221432,
                  "_source": {...
```

I figured just doing something like this would solve it
es_return.responses.hits.total but I get the error: "can not read "total" of undefined.

How do I access the es data in the new format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `es_return.responses` is an array so you ned to reference each response elements by index.

So, for accessing the response to the first `multi_match` query, you need to use `es_return.responses[0].hits.total` and for accessing the response to the `mlt` query, you need to use `es_return.responses[1].hits.total`.

Comment: thanks for the clear and concise answer, I forgot about index.